# uri is too long when I try to send a base64 using xamarin forms

Tags: http, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin.forms and System.Net.Http;

I am sending a photo using a post function which is this:

```
public static async Task<String> PostImagemAsync(User user)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {

                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(0);
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", user.usua_login));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("senha", user.usua_senha));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("foto", user.cont_imagem));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("json", "1"));

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://ws.neosuite.com.br/login.asmx/foto", content);

                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
                json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);

                var userImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

                return userImage[0].cont_imagem;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

My image (foto) is a base64 And it does I get this error when I try to send it:

> Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

How to solve that?

Comment: is this an exception on the client, or an error from the server?

Comment: I read about it and it seems my base64 string is much big to the uri

Answer (score 1):

Without adding your POST content into url, add that to body using following code

```
var uri = new Uri (string.Format ("http://ws.neosuite.com.br/login.asmx/foto", string.Empty));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (user);//user object or you can create your own jason here
var content = new StringContent (json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync (uri, content);
```